# Eigen-like algebra library with Tensor & Autodiff support

Tags: open-source, c++, math, matrix

So far, I have used [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) in my C++ projects. However, I'm developing a new project where I need Tensors and Autodiff.

Although Eigen has Tensor and Audodiff modules, they are not supported (they are indeed part of unsupported Eigen's features). In the current stage, these Eigen modules do not fit my needs. I [opened an issue](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/2714) and [submitted an MR](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/merge_requests/1390) to Eigen's maintainers. However, I'm unsure if they plan to work on this on a short horizon.

What I need is support for contractions, convolutions, etc. Something like this:

```
Tensor<AutoDiff_T, 2> A(2, 2);
Tensor<AutoDiff_T, 2> B(2, 2);
auto dims = ...;
Tensor<AutoDiff_T, 2> C = A.contract(B, dims);
```

Does someone have a recommendation for a similar library with production-ready support to Tensors+Autodiff?